# iOS 9.0 assetContentChanged sometimes returns false

Tags: ios, photokit

When listening on changes from the Photo Library in `photoLibraryDidChange()`, 
`PHObjectChangeDetails.assetContentChanged` sometimes returns `false` for assets whose contents definitely have changed (it has been cropped). But somehow `assetContentChanged` on the change details for that asset returns `false`.

Comment: Have you tried this in iOS 10? I believe this is a known bug in iOS 9...

Comment: mmm would it cause the library to return stall images? cuz that's what i see. I get a librarydidchange, and i try to refresh the image by requesting it. But sometimes it returns a non cropped image (stale) :(

Comment: Okay but that's not what you asked.

Comment: lol you are right. this is actually very helpful. i'll see if this issue and the refreshing issue repro on iOS10